# how to auto generate ID from phpmyadmin

Tags: php

I am currently working on leave form.

I want to auto-generate leave id as it is set as my primary key in the database.

I am using phpmyadmin for my databsase.

Answer (score 3):

login to your phpmyadmin

go to your **database-> table->structure->edit**

there you can find a AI field which is auto_increment check it.

Answer (score 2):

There are few steps to make auto increment for a column in phpMyAdmin.

Click on ***Table*** >  **Structure** tab > Under **Action** click on **Change** on the popup window scroll left and check **A_I**. Also make sure you have selected **None** for **Default**[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to just make the leave_id field as primary key and check the A_I checkbox in your table dafination [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```